# Under what circumstances will a browser send byte range requests?

Tags: http, browser

I think the question speaks for itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, very rarely. Pausing and resuming downloads is one example, and using '[progressive download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download)' for pseudo streaming, although in the latter case, I'm only aware of flash clients implementing this - not browsers.